# How to hold payment in paygate for a while?

Tags: php, payment-gateway

HI all,

I have a query regarding holding the payment in **PAYGATE PAYMENT GATEWAY.**

Here is the problem in brief. I am doing a website where the payment should be made only a certain members buy the product.

For Example if there is an iPhone in my site, then that particular phone must be buy by certain quantities which given by admin. It may be done one by one user or a single user can buy all the quantities at a single time.

**In this case as a developer how can i able to hold the payment which received by user?**

Because i don't want to receive the payments until the certain quantities bought. Because if certain quantities were not buy i need to refund the money to their account. We don't like to do this process.

That's why we are looking for holding the payment.

Is it possible or what is the best way to solve this problem?

Please let me know what is you professional opinion?

thanks in advance...

Please let me know what is you professional opinion?

Comment: I think that is much depend of the bank, seeks help from http://money.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a [Authorization Hold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization_hold), I don't think PHP will handle this but it's the type of request you make to the credit card processing company. I'm sure if you're using a payment gateway/api they have some documentation on this. I would send a question to PAYGATE about the functionality you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, It all depends on the PAYGATEWAY side, php itself can do nothing with the matter, with your php program you need only to send data to GATEWAY and after you need only to have the return file to show up in your system, of course if you want to do this, 'cause you don't need.

If you are using PayPal it has a lot of information, just read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

For payGate integration you can use the bellow link for Authrization implementations like Authorize, Capture, Pay, Void, Refund
Like: https://github.com/PayGate/sample-code-php
PayHost
PayHost is PayGate’s enterprise API which offers a powerful, flexible payment processing interface with many possible applications such as e-commerce, mobile payments, recurring payments and call centre payments but is not limited to these applications. Payments can be processed either via a host-to-host integration or redirected to a PayGate-hosted payments page, and a number of international and regional payment methods are supported.

**SingleFollowup**

- Query
- Void
- Settlement
- Refund